# How to avoid that a deprecated method is called in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, orientation

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` is deprecated since iOS 8. So the `WillRotate` is also deprecated in Xamarin iOS. But `WillRotate` will still be called on iOS 8.

How can I assure that this method is not called by an iOS 8 device? Do I need something like a compiler directive? `RespondsToSelector` will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's deprecated and you compiled your app using latest SDK target, it will not being called.

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 7 and I build with the latest SDK (iOS 8). Here the function is called in the iOS 8 simulator.

Comment: You're using not the latest target.

Comment: OK. How can I use the latest target? Where can I find the option for this?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/, set SDK version.

Comment: Project Options > iOS Build > General > SDK Options > SDK version: Standard. The current setting is standard. I can choose between Standard, 7.1 and 8. There is no *Minimum OS version* option here. So should I set the SDK version to 8.0 and the deprecated function will not be called? Also currently `UIAlertView` and so on works on iOS 8. If I change the settings will `UIAlertView` stop working?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality depends on the method being implemented or not.   While many APIs were deprecated, the functionality is still present for backwards compatibility.

What this means in this particular case is that if you implement the method (or any of the other supporting methods in the family), the method will be invoked.   If you do not implement it, the new methods will be called.

Which ones depend on what exactly the underlying framework is using to probe for.   They are likely using RespondsToSelector() and based on presence/absence of a method execute one code path or another.

Comment: In my case I have to implement `WillRotate` to support iOS 7 devices. On iOS 8 I get my function called twice, because `WillRotate` is called additionally on iOS 8 where it shouldn't be called. It's not a big problem but it costs a little bit performance because the same work is done twice.

Comment: `UpdateViewConstraints` is always called on iOS 8. On iOS 7 I'm using `WillRotate` to call `UpdateViewConstraints` explicitly. So iOS 8 is updating my constraints twice.